# MFC is posible to create three View on a Dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, view, mfc

Is it possible to create three View in dialog, or Create 4 View and hide 
one of them? 
E.g

[image]

Comment: The best solution, if you can, is to use SDI, with split window ... much more easy and reliable !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitter on a dialog app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943851/splitter-on-a-dialog-app)

Answer (score 0):

Although it *might* be possible, I strongly advise against it.

The MFC framework (and document/view architecture) rely heavily on certain relationship between objects. Even if you manage to place a CView into a CDialog, you will soon discover that something is not working right.

As was suggested by flaviu2, I would create a full-feature MFC application and make it behave as a dialog, if that is really what you want. What exactly do you want from your dialog?